# How does the cost and traffic work when a rendering Lambda function fetches data from a backend Lambda function in the same AWS region?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I came across this post online:

https://aws.amazon.com/ko/blogs/compute/building-server-side-rendering-for-react-in-aws-lambda/

> The React app is rendered with a Lambda function. The CloudFront
> distribution is configured to forward requests from the /ssr path to
> the API Gateway endpoint. This calls the Lambda function where the
> rendering is happening. While rendering the requested page, the Lambda
> function calls the backend API to fetch the data. It returns a static
> HTML page with all the data. This page may be cached in CloudFront to
> optimize subsequent requests.

In this case, does the rendering Lambda send an HTTP fetch request to the backend Lambda's API Gateway endpoint to retrieve the data?

If the rendering Lambda and the backend Lambda are in the same region, are they considered internal AWS traffic?

Even though it's an HTTP endpoint, if it's treated as internal traffic, what would the cost be?